# Chances of collision of GIT hashes when only using first 6 characters of a hash

Tags: git, hash

Hey guys we're using multiple repositories, and storing the hashes in a DB as an identifier.

The question is, I only have a short hash (AKA: 8df639) instead of a full hash (AKA: 8df639b301a1e10c36cc2f03bbdf8863) later in my application. I though about using a select statement as follows

```
SELECT foo FROM table WHERE hash LIKE '8df639%' LIMIT 1
```

But am starting to fear that I might run into hash collision later on as hash start to pile up.

The question is, is this a reasonable fear, or will this be ok as I am at 36^4? (1679616 combinations), due to these being from different repositories, is there a real likely hood of colliding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good idea to store the entire hash if possible.

Git itself will accept short hashes (usually 7 characters, not 6), but only as long as they remain unique. If you ever generate two commits starting with `8df639b`, you'll be forced to enter more of the hash before Git will recognize the commit you're talking about.

As an aside, I believe you actually have 16,777,216 combinations with six characters (16^6), but you are very likely to get a collision well before generating that many commit objects.

Comment: Yes, assuming uniform distributions, the chance of a collision hash is much the same as the chance of two people in a room having the same birthday, the so-called ["birthday paradox"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Cast_as_a_collision_problem).

Comment: Gah, broke the link (and meant to say 2 or more people).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Cast_as_a_collision_problem